# How does MEF affect your application load times?

Tags: mef

I'm currently investigating MEF to know the feasibility of some kind of plugin subsystem for a software we are writing at my company. One of the first questions that came to my mind is to know the influence of MEF components in the application load time.

Moreover, if that's something of significant weight, is it possible to load those components completely at runtime?

Thanks in advance
Roman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm building an application completely on top of MEF and the load time is quite good.  Yes, you can instantiate objects at runtime; it's called [Lazy Imports](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lazy%20Exports&referringTitle=Guide).